# Output file in PHP encoded as OCS-2 Big Endian

Tags: php, encoding, endianness, ucs2

How can I write a file in PHP that has the encoding OCS-2 Big Endian? An industrial system I am trying to integrate with requires this encoding format.

To simplify the problem, supposing the content I was trying to write to a file was stored in the variable *$sXML*, in this case XML content with encoding set in the XML header ready:

```
$sXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16BE"?>';
$sXML .= '<envelope><node>1</node><node>2</node><node>3</node></envelope>';
/* Insert solution here */
file_put_contents( 'filename.xml', $sXML );
```

So far I have tried such as:

1. `$sXML = iconv( '', 'UCS-2BE', $sXML );`
2. `$sXML = html_entity_decode( htmlentities( $sXML, ENT_QUOTES, 'Windows-1252' ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UCS-2BE' );`
3. `$sXML = mb_convert_encoding( $sXML, 'UCS-2BE', 'HTML-ENTITIES' );`

And while all of these ruin the human readability of the file generated in Notepad++, none of them cause the file encoding to be set to UCS-2BE.

If you're not familiar with OCS-2 Big Endian encoding, this might prove to be essential/helpful reading: [Better Explained (blog): Understanding Big and Little Endian Byte Order](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/).

I've tried looking through the other questions here on StackOverflow but found a solution to this specific problem, or managed to adapt any of the others to this. Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: is it the PHP or the output that needs to be UCS-2 Big Endian?

Comment: It's the output - $sXML. Doesn't make any difference to me whether I get the output via file_put_contents or echo or any other method, just need it with the right encoding! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using simplexml?

Comment: Sure I can use simplexml functions for generating/parsing XML but I was just trying to give a very simple example as the issue here is the UCS-2BE encoding, the content of the file doesn't really matter. It could be any text or binary data and I'd still have the same issue. Big Endian involves writing bytes in a different grouping and order.

Comment: well I was just thinking that, in regards to XML, you could use its built in functions to save to file.  I apologise that I didn't read far enough to see that you will be saving more than just XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was very close, and eventually I worked it out. The verified working solution is as follows:

```
$sXML = pack( 'n', 0xFEFF ) . iconv( '', 'UCS-2BE', $sXML );
```

Thank you all for your help troubleshooting this problem.